# Passing NSString in NSURL causes app crash

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsurl

I am passing `NSString` to `NSURL` and app crashes. I think this is  due to 's used in `NSString`

NSLog of the NSString is

```
http://www.test.com/?AssessmentID=040714114412 &QuestionID=113&ResponseText=yes&AssessmentName=Housekeeping&AssessmentDate=11:44:21&AssessmentQuestion=Use the guest’s or employee’s name.&ResponseComment=No comment&DepartmentID=9&SectionName=Service Standards
```

here is the exception

```
[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
```

I think it is crashing due to guest's 's

Comment: check my answer and if you satisfied my answer so please upvote my answer.

Comment: @user3110080 The right approach is mentioned there in my answer. It's simple & effective.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your URL is not properly encoded. Take this & modify your code accordingly.

```
NSString *relativeURL = @"http://www.something with Space and parameters";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[relativeURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This is the right approach rather than replacing white spaces with `%20`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried out the following piece of code and it is working for me... can you do this as per the following code!

```
NSString *relativeToURL = @"http://www.test.com/?AssessmentID=040714114412 &QuestionID=113&ResponseText=yes&AssessmentName=Housekeeping&AssessmentDate=11:44:21&AssessmentQuestion=Use the guest’s or employee’s name.&ResponseComment=No comment&DepartmentID=9&SectionName=Service Standards";
NSURL *url =     [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:relativeToURL];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```